# My function does not modify its inputs

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ and have this small beginner question:

why does the `standardize` function not modify its inputs?

To help with the answers, I have posted an executing code at Coliru 
 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87a1b4609a20acad) 
 and the sources of my program below.

Referring to the code, the question would be: why isn't what's 
printed after `outside` the same as what's printed after `inside`?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void standardize(const int n,const float x[],float ave,float sct){
    float acc=0.0f,sum=0.0f;
    sum=std::accumulate(x,x+n,0.0f);
    ave=sum/(float)n;
    std::for_each(x,x+n,[&](const float d){acc+=(d-ave)*(d-ave);});
    sct=std::sqrt(acc/(float)(n-1));
    std::cout << "inside" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ave << std::endl;
    std::cout << sct << std::endl;
    return;
}
int main(){
    const int n=1024;
    float a2[n];
    float part0=0.0f,part1=0.0f;
    std::srand(std::time(0)); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)      a2[i]=std::rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    standardize(n,a2,part0,part1);
    std::cout << "outside" << std::endl;
    std::cout << part0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << part1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should read about passing parameters by reference

Comment: @o_weisman: thanks! I googled it and it solved the problem. I'm sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: @user189035, even though this is basic it is a well asked question, I upvoted. You need to pass by non-const reference if you wish to modify the variables you passed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing `ave` and `sct` by **values**. Your `standardize` method modifies copies of those arguments, letting unchanged the original ones declared in `main()`

Consider passing them by reference:

```
void standardize(const int n,const float x[],float& ave,float& sct)
```